# How to visualise a weighted edgelist as a directed network

Tags: r, igraph

I have an edge list in Excel that looks like this:

```
from   to   weighted
a      b      5
c      b      0
d      b      20
a      c      1
b      c      30
d      f      1
```

How can I read this edge list and visualize it as a weighted network? I currently have:

```r
library(igraph)
library("readxl")

data <- read_excel("Sample.xlsx")
g <- graph_from_data_frame(data, directed = TRUE, vertices = NULL)
plot(g)
```

But the plot doesn't show the edge weights. What function should I use to visualize the weights?

Comment: To plot the thickness of the edge by weight see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301119/change-edge-thickness-in-igraph-plot-r-according-to-edge-attributes or add weight as labels: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077403/show-edge-attributes-as-label-with-igraph

Answer (score 0):

U can use the plot parameters like edge.width , vertex.size, edge.color etc to visualize ur plot. Try below approach to do this

```
library(igraph)
library(readxl)

data <- read_excel("Sample.xlsx")
g <- graph_from_data_frame(data, directed = TRUE, vertices = NULL)

# Use ur weighted column data here
edge_weights <- E(g)$weighted
max_weight <- max(edge_weights)
min_weight <- min(edge_weights)
scaled_weights <- rescale(edge_weights, to = c(1, 10))  

plot(g, edge.width = scaled_weights, edge.color = "gray", vertex.color = "lightblue", vertex.size = 30)
```

Comment: thank you for yor answer! I try to run this but fllowing warning:
> edge_weights <- E(g)$weighted
> max_weight <- max(edge_weights)
Warning message:
In max(edge_weights) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
> min_weight <- min(edge_weights)
Warning message:
In min(edge_weights) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
> scaled_weights <- rescale(edge_weights, to = c(1, 10))  
Error in rescale(edge_weights, to = c(1, 10)) : 
  could not find function "rescale"
>